# Changing background color of button on click with JQuery doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a button that I want to change its color when the user clicks on it, but it doesn't work and I can't figure out why.

This is what I've tried until now.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {


 });


$('#canvasButtons button').click(function () {
        $('#canvasButtons').children().removeClass('selected-button');
        $(this).addClass('selected-button');
        });
```

```css
.video-buttons button {
    width: 200px !important;
    height: 66px !important;
    background-color: #484848 !important;
    cursor: pointer !important;
    margin-right: 50px;
}

.selected-button {
  background-color: red !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="display: flex; align-items: center; flex-direction: column;" class="video-buttons" id="canvasButtons">
  <button id="modifyButton">
    <div class="vertical-line"></div>
    <span>Modify B Box</span>
  </button>
</div>
```

I've added the code snippet here.
Can you please let me know why it doesn't work?

Comment: Can you do it on codepen or here for testing?

Comment: 1) don't put DIVs in your button
2) check your reference in js

Comment: @Undry relevant for your `2)` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827965/is-putting-a-div-inside-an-anchor-ever-correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're having specificity issues in your CSS rather than a problem in you JS.

The specificity of `.selected-button` is lower than `.video-buttons button` even when using `!important` everywhere (which you should avoid).

So to get this to work you have to make the `selected-button` selector higher specificity than the default styles for it.

`.video-buttons button.selected-button` should do the trick.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#canvasButtons button').click(function () {
    $('#canvasButtons').children().removeClass('selected-button');
    $(this).addClass('selected-button');
  });
});
```

```css
.video-buttons button {
  width: 200px !important;
  height: 66px !important;
  background-color: #484848 !important;
  cursor: pointer !important;
  margin-right: 50px;
}

.video-buttons button.selected-button {
  background-color: red !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="display: flex; align-items: center; flex-direction: column;" class="video-buttons" id="canvasButtons">
  <button id="modifyButton">
    <div class="vertical-line"></div>
    <span>Modify B Box</span>
  </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
    
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#canvasButtons button').click(function () {
        $('#canvasButtons').children().removeClass('selected-button');
        $(this).addClass('selected-button');
      });
    });
```

```css
.video-buttons button {
      width: 200px !important;
      height: 66px !important;
      background-color: #484848 !important;
      cursor: pointer !important;
      margin-right: 50px;
      -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    color:#fff;outline:none;border:none;
    }

    .video-buttons button.selected-button {
      background-color: green !important;
      -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="display: flex; align-items: center; flex-direction: column;" class="video-buttons" id="canvasButtons">
      <button id="modifyButton">
        <div class="vertical-line"></div>
        <span>Modify B Box</span>
      </button>
    </div>
```

please see snippet this will help you. I put also animation speed for changing color. you can manage as per your requirement.

Comment: Why create another answer that has less explanation, use the same solution and then adds unneeded things like color transition?